# Play Framework New Project in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework

When I create a new project in Intellij, I got these error message in which I dont really know how to mitigate or approach to solve this problem.

Im currently using Intellij IDEA 15

Is there someone who knows about this error?

```
Unknown Error!
Could not retrieve latest Aspose Maven Artifacts!
```

Comment: it looks like you're referring to Aspose Java APIs from Maven and somehow it is not working fine for you. Are you using some Aspose APIs in your project? Are you working on someone else project and the project referring to Aspose APIs? Please check and share.

Comment: no, im creating a new project in intellij

Comment: Frankly, it shouldn't give you this error if the project is not involved with Aspose APIs in anyway! We can only investigate it further, if we can figure out where and how Aspose APIs are involved with the project. Maybe you could send such a sample project to our team which can help us reproduce the issue at our end? http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/default.aspx

Comment: oh i think i fixed it, I just disabled maven aspose plugin \in intellij,. thanks anyway

Comment: that's solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For any future searchers who find this post when having this problem, it should be noted that in the follow-up comments to the original question, the OP stated that simply disabling the Aspose plugin in IntelliJ solved the problem.

I was having the same issue trying to create a new project from a Maven archetype provided by org.openjfx and I was getting the same error that the OP did. When I went into IntelliJ's app preferences, under Plugins, I disabled the Aspose plugin and this solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in Intellij 2016. The only work around in existence is upgrade to the latest version of Intellij.